# Magento Maximum Allowed Order Amount per customer or customer group

Tags: magento

I’m setting up a trade website for my company and right now I encounter this issue.

We have more than 10+ trade clients and obviously I don’t want to setup 10+ different websites for each of them. Thus, I’ve setup 10+ customer groups with different prices. However, we want to set a maximum order amount for some client who consistently failed to pay us after 1 month credit term. For this sort of customers, we’d like to set $1 (or any small amount) maximum order limit so that they can not order from our trade website any more till they pay us and I will manually increase their limit from the backend.

Can someone help me with this request? Or point me to the right direction of how to achieve my desired solution please?

Answer (score 1):

You could follow something like [this](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-maximum-allowed-order-amount/). In fact, you need to filter by customer group, so could get the customer object with:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($quote->getCustomerId());
```

And then filter by Customer Group:

```
if ($customer->getGroupId() == 'INSERT ID HERE' && (float)$quote->getGrandTotal() > (float)$this->_helper->getSingleOrderTopAmount())
```

Comment: Thank you Rafael. I've read the link you provided before posting my question in this forum. However, this tutorial can only set the maximum order per website but not per customer group. I will send your recommended code to my developer to see if it would help him to find a solution for me. Many thanks!